# Geocoding Australian postcodes - MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, geocoding

How do I plot suburbs/location onto a map? I have a list of suburb postcode and their names in Excel. What is the process to plot them onto a Map? I'm in Australia. I use MapInfo Professional 10.1. !

Comment: Unless you have location information, you'll need to geocode them. That is cross reference your table of postal codes with another file that also has the location of each postcode. I'll leave someone local to tell you how you might do this...

Comment: Let me clarify further. I have an Australian map.tab file and i have an excel list of all postcode/suburb location. So does this mean I will have to geocode them?

Answer (score 1):

The Australian Postcode dataset is not free and can be obtained from a number of resellers.  A description of the dataset and where to buy can be found on the [PSMA](http://www.psma.com.au/products/postcodeboundaries.html) website.

[Postal Areas](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/Latestproducts/AF901D4830BD2F20CA25720A007E71D6) are Australian Bureau of Statistics (ABS) approximations of Australia Post postcodes, created by allocating whole Collection Districts (CDs) on a 'best fit' basis to postcodes.  Digital boundaries are [available](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/d3310114.nsf/4a256353001af3ed4b2562bb00121564/60fabd1bcba7bd2cca25721300127fad!OpenDocument), I think for free but I'm not sure, from the ABS.

Comment: yep, they are free to download from the [ABS](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/2923.0.30.0012006?OpenDocument)

Comment: I have downloaded the data, it's in .MIF format which I'm not sure what/how to access this data. Any ideas?

Comment: Table -> Import

Comment: So what is the next step after importing? I'm a newbie and need your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the digital boundaries in MapInfo format from the Australian Bureau of Statistics page under document [2923.0.30.001](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/2923.0.30.0012006?OpenDocument).

Note that Postcode boundaries are not available freely in Australia - the next best thing is Postal Areas, which are similar but not identical. See [here](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/D3110124.NSF/24e5997b9bf2ef35ca2567fb00299c59/53bbe9630b24d6f4ca256c3a000475b8!OpenDocument#Postal%20Area) for further information.

I'm not a MapInfo user, so I don't know the exact terminology - but basically you'll want to join the Excel table to the digital boundaries. In Esri terms that's regarded as a [table join](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_joining_and_relating_tables).